# How to change background color per dynamically created FlexBox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, jinja2

So for a bit of context, the project I am working on currently is creating a dashboard that will show a location which in turn is an IP Address. So I am dynamically creating a FlexBox per location in the dashboard that will change color depending on the ms (millisecond) response time of a ping on the IP address associated the location. So the issue I am running into is that the background color is not changing per FlexBox like it should be. It is using the last location in the list of locations and making every location that color. I have provided a photo with an example of what I am talking about. The color code is yellow, so the FlexBox background should be yellow but instead it is coming up as green instead. Now if the last FlexBox in the dashboard is yellow then all of the boxes are yellow instead of green.

[image: Example of FlexBox that is not is not the correct color.]

I have gone through the Flask documentation [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/), and haven't found anything helpful yet.

Below is the code I am using to make this happen. It is a flask app, so it is a combination of HTML, CSS, and Python.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css">

<style>
.flex-container > div {
  width: 15%;
  margin: .5%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200%;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: rgb(226, 225, 225);
  {% for k, v in locations_dicts.items() %}
    background-color:{{ v[1] }};
  {% endfor %}
}

.flex-container > div:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}  
</style>
</head>

<div>
    <h2 class="dashboard-title">Mikrotik Dashboard</h2>
</div>

<div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="/">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="/add">Add Location</a>
    <a href="/remove">Remove Location</a>
</div>

<div id="cell" class="flex-container" onclick="remove()">
    {% for k, v in locations_dicts.items() %}
      <div>{{ k }}<br>{{ v[0] }}<br>{{ v[1] }}<br>{{ v[2] }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<script id="remove">
  function remove() {
      var remove;
      if (confirm("Do you wish to remove this location?\n(This currently does nothing.)")) {
          remove = true;
      } else {
          remove = false;
      }
      return remove
  }
</script>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"> 

</html>
```

Comment: Make css classes for each color, then dynamically assign classes to your flex-boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented above, but I will try to expound here. Please forgive me, as I am not a python developer.

```
<style>
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

you should delete the following from your style

```
{% for k, v in locations_dicts.items() %}
    background-color:{{ v[1] }};
{% endfor %}
```

then in your html/python

```
<div id="cell" class="flex-container" onclick="remove()">
    {% for k, v in locations_dicts.items() %}
        <div class="{{ v[1] }}">{{ k }}<br>{{ v[0] }}<br>{{ v[1] }}<br>{{ v[2] }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Edit: to suggest removal of php (background-color) in style.

Comment: You my friend are a GENIUS! This worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

correct me if I am worng but what you want to do is to give a background color to each flexbox depending on ping right? so you basically have 3 colors Green for good Yellow average and Red for bad, if that is correct well I dont know anything about python but I know HTM5 CSS3 and Javascript. And that can be easily done in 2 ways through css or javascript.

first look at your code: Since I dont know python I have to guess a few things, for example  this code looks like you are creating some css rules.

```
<style>
    .flex-container > div {   
    ------some style-----   
    {% for k, v in locations_dicts.items() %}
    background-color:{{ v[1] }};
    {% endfor %}
    }
    -----more style-----
</style>
```

Now the that part is the interesting one I dont know from where the hell you are getting the values for your variables "K" and "V" and I dont know python but to me looks like a 'for loop' that generates a bunch of divs inside a parent div with the class flex-container  until it reaches the {% endfor %} and "v[1]" is the color, and that is why you assingned the background-color using v[1]

Now, the problem with that logic is that actually makes no sense because if I am correct and it is in did a "for loop" what it does is to Over-write your CSS rule over and over and over until it reaches the *{% endfor %}* and that is why all of your divs looks the same.

Second look at your code: (Man your HTML is awful)  again I don't know anything about python but it looks like you can pass some variables along with HTML tags pretty much like you can in a string template using Javscript.

```
{% for k, v in locations_dicts.items() %}
<div>{{ k }}<br>{{ v[0] }}<br>{{ v[1] }}<br>{{ v[2] }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Looking at the image you attached to the question I could make some asumptions: "K" is the name of a city and "V" is obiously an array and it has at least 3 values [0] is the IP [1] is a String representing a color Green or Yellow (and probably there is a Red one) and [2] is the ping and it is represented with another String (22ms, 18ms and so on).
If I am correct and you can pass HTML tags and CSS rules along with your variables the solution will be as follows.

The CSS solution:
You have to re-think your logic, think out of the box or in this case "out of the container". Basically leave the coloring out of the equation, and don't dinamically generate your CSS rules. Then your code should look like this.

```
{% for k, v in locations_dicts.items() %}
<div class="box-{{ v[1] }}">{{ k }}<br>{{ v[0] }}<br>{{ v[2] }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

meaning that each div will get one of the available colors stored in v[1] and you will pass that color as a part of a class, so you will end up with 3 classes
"box-Green" "box-Yellow" "box-Red"

Javascript Solution:
You can use Javascript and assign a class to the divs acording with the color, but you have to pass the color as a data attribute and your code should look like this:

```
{% for k, v in locations_dicts.items() %}
<div data-color="{{ v[1] }}">{{ k }}<br>{{ v[0] }}<br>{{ v[2] }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The Javascript code:

```
function coloringDivs(){
  const selectGreen = document.querySelectorAll('[data-color="Green"]');
  for (let i = 0; i < selectGreen.length; i++) {
    selectGreen[i].setAttribute("class", "box-Green");
  };
  const selectYellow = document.querySelectorAll('[data-color="Yellow"]');
  for (let i = 0; i < selectYellow.length; i++) {
    selectYellow[i].setAttribute("class", "box-Yellow");
  };
  const selectRed = document.querySelectorAll('[data-color="Red"]');
  for (let i = 0; i < selectRed.length; i++) {
    selectRed[i].setAttribute("class", "box-Red");
  };
};
coloringDivs();
```

The CSS rules:

```
.box-Green{background-color: green;}
.box-Red{background-color: red;}
.box-Yellow{background-color: orange;}
/*orange because yellow is actually a horrible color for a background*/
```

Now your HTML my friend, I am sorry man I don't want to be mean but it's Horrible, like a 1990's nightmare web page, it makes me cringe, I will sugest some changes:

1. The use of flexbox is discouraged since is old and grid is way better.
2. Make use of HTML5 Semantic Elements
3. Don't use inline styles unless it is absolutely necessary (no seriously, don't use them)

I think this will do for your html markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <h2 class="dashboard-title">Mikrotik Dashboard</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active"href="/">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="/add">Add Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="/remove">Remove Location</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<main>
<section>
    {% for k, v in locations_dicts.items() %}
      <article>{{ k }}<br>{{ v[0] }}<br>{{ v[1] }}<br>{{ v[2] }}</article>
    {% endfor %}
</section>
</main>
<script src="main.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this pen you can see how does the code looks like
[GO TO CODE PEN](https://codepen.io/jeanbelmont/pen/BPZdvQ/right/)

**Bonus I included some Javascript for your close Button**

Comment: This is an amazing answer and you are right my HTML and CSS are horrible. I am really new to both, slowly learning my way through them both. Python is were I am most comfortable but thank you so much for all your input and I will for sure be looking at cleaning up the HTML and removing the inline styles. This project is very much in the beginning stages and I wanted to get a working concept before I worried about prettying up the code. Now that I have a working concept a lot of refactoring is going to take place and your suggestions will guide a lot of that. So again thank you for ur answer :)